# Can't change from AT mode to API in Xbee

Tags: xbee, zigbee

I have 2 Xbee Pro S3B (Family Set : XBEE-PRO XSC (S3B) 9600 - Product family : XBP9B).

I want to use them in API mode but i can't because i can't find the option in XCTU(version 6.4.0) and the interface of XCTU itself is wired (Instead of PAN ID there is Modem VID).

[The interface of XCTU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGKBR.png)

The problem is that i Can't find the AP tap that can enable the API mode but there is another tap which is **MD** RF mode and the modes in it are

1. Peer to Peer(Transparent)[0]
2. Unavailable[1
3. Unavailable[2
4. Repeater[3]
5. Repeater End Node[4]

And i assume that the unavailable mode is the Api and Api with escape mode.

After that i tried to access the xbee with console configuration mode (AT command mode) and changing it to API and also got an ERROR.

[AT Command mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpsg5.png)

Hint: The 2 modules are working fine in AT mode.I tried them a lot and they are fine.

Answer (score 0):

The XBee Pro S3B is a low-speed, long-range module that (I believe) is point-to-point.  It does not support API mode.